# bot-script goto not working out of main section

Tags: gupshup

I'm writing a bot with gupshup and my code have two sections, the [main] section and [send] section
When I try goto inside the main section it's working very well but in the send section it is not working

Answer (score 0):

`:goto` only works within the scope of a section/module and used to call labels present in the same section. Hence, you are unable to use `:goto` to call a label present in another section/module.

You can use `:call {script_file_name}.{section/module name}` command to call a particular section and invoke the very 1st statement.
Eg: Refer to gupshup.io [doc](https://www.gupshup.io/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/modules)